# Can't capture packets from namespace interface

Tags: networking, mininet, sdn, openvswitch, linux-namespaces

## My goal

Hi everyone! So my goal is to run a python listener on an interface inside a namespace to catch `EAP` messages.

To be more specific: I'm running a [Faucet SDN controller](https://github.com/faucetsdn/faucet) and a topology created in [mininet](https://github.com/mininet/mininet). In faucet SDN controller there is a module called [Chewie](https://github.com/faucetsdn/chewie) which is responsible for handling 802.1X messages (acts as an authenticator). It works by listening on a port that is specified in a config (NFV port). Than it checks values against RADIUS server and sends a response.

## A problem

My problem is that I can't get Chewie to actually capture packets that are sent to the interface.
What I think is happening is that Chewie is listening on an interface that are visible from host side (e.g. veths interfaces, in my case `s1-eth3`)

```
root@ubuntu2004:~# ip link show
[...]
33: s1-eth3@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master ovs-system state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:90:29:3a:15:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
```

but what it should actually listen on is an interface seen from inside a namespace - in my case `listener-eth0` (I'm really sorry if I'm speaking nonsens here, I'm in the process of learning about all of this stuff)

```
mininet> listener ifconfig
listener-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::2095:66ff:feab:8918  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 22:95:66:ab:89:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31  bytes 3536 (3.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13  bytes 1006 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
[...]
```

And I don't know how can I provide access to this port, because just giving a name isn't enough (I get error that this device could not be found)

I know that Chewie is working because when I sent a EAP packet directly to the lo interface and set Faucet/Chewie to listen on it it reacted correctly and started authentication process:
[image: Wireshark capture of EAP protocol working]

Also I checked whether packet are routed by the switch correctly but it's also true because:

- wireshark sees EAP start packets
  [image: Wireshark capture of EAP start packet visible on the interface]
- there is a flow installed that corresponds to this traffic - here I'm not sure why MAC address is being modified:

```
cookie=0x5adc15c0, duration=906.988s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=20481,in_port="s1-eth1",dl_type=0x888e actions=mod_dl_dst:00:00:00:00:00:01,output:"s1-eth3"
```

## What I tried

- to set listening on `lo` (in Faucet config) and running wpa_supplicant on lo from host - it worked, Chewie got a packet
- to set listening on a standard interface (in my case `enp0s3`) and added it to the openvswitch. Chewie didn't got a packet
- to set listening on a created interface by mininet (`s1-eth3`) - Chewie didn't get a packet

## Additional info

There is not a lot of information out there about this configuration. Bits and pieces that I was able to find:

- [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lusbAfS5png) - youtube video that describes how Chewie works and also has a little bit of information about configuration
- [Faucet Readthedocs](https://docs.faucet.nz/en/latest/configuration.html#x-dp) - a little explanation about possible configuration and how it should work
- [A file responsible for handling nfv sockets from Chewie github](https://github.com/faucetsdn/chewie/blob/main/chewie/nfv_sockets.py#L39)

## Minimum setup needed to recreate it

- installed mininet with this topology:

```py
from mininet.topo import Topo  
  
  
class MyTopo(Topo):  
    "Simple topology example."  
  
    def build(self):  
        "Create custom topo."  
  
        # Add hosts and switches  
        client = self.addHost('client')  
        server = self.addHost('server')  
        listener = self.addHost('listener')  
        switch = self.addSwitch('s1')  
  
        # Add links  
        self.addLink(client, switch)  
        self.addLink(server, switch)  
        self.addLink(listener, switch)  
  
  
topos = {'mytopo': (lambda: MyTopo())}
```

- installed faucet (service with root privileges because chewie has to be able to open a socket), with this configuration:

```yaml
vlans:
    office:
        vid: 100
        description: "office network"
    radius:
        vid: 200
        description: "radius network"

dps:
    sw1:
        dp_id: 0x1
        dot1x:
            nfv_intf: s1-eth3
            nfv_sw_port: 3
            radius_ip: 127.0.0.1
            radius_port: 18120
            radius_secret: SECRET
        hardware: "Open vSwitch"
        interfaces:
            1:
                name: "RADIUS for host 1"
                dot1x: true
                dot1x_dyn_acl: true
                native_vlan: office
            2:
                name: "host2"
                description: "host2 network namespace"
                native_vlan: office
            3:
                name: "eap listening port"
                output_only: true
acls:
    block-ping:
        - rule:
            dl_type: 0x800      # IPv4
            ip_proto: 1         # ICMP
            actions:
                allow: False
        - rule:
            dl_type: 0x86dd     # IPv6
            ip_proto: 58        # ICMPv6
            actions:
                allow: False
```

- wpa supplicant with this example configuration:

```
ctrl_interface=/tmp/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
ap_scan=0

network={
 key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
 eap=MD5
 identity="admin"
 password="test123"
 eapol_flags=0
}
```

Then run faucet

```
systemctl start faucet
```

And run mininet with configured topology

```
sudo mn --custom mytopo.py --topo mytopo --controller=remote
```

Then try to run `wpa_supplicant` from the client and see if chewie is receiving EAP packet (logs can be found in `/var/log/faucet/faucet.log`). There should be info about received packet.

NOTE: To complete login RADIUS server is needed but for now I just want Chewie to receive a EAP packet.

If anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. The interface which Chewie listen on shouldn't be in namespace. In mininet configuration I had to add "inNamespace=False" to get the interface out of the namespace. Now when I listen on it everything works fine :)